# Hide div from code behind function whose Status is 0 in database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have given a task to hide and show divs that contain buttons on the basis of 0 and 1 status in database  this will be set by admin that which div is to show and hide to relevant user;

**Problem is,front End hideid() function executes after Code behind function getpermission(),so that last div id assigned to hiddenfield only that div Hides, rest of remain unhide**
Front-End:-

```
 <div class="row">        
    <div id="dbtn1" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Button  ID="btn1" CssClass=" thumbnail shadow tile tile-small btn-block tilepink " ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Add Party" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </div>

    <div id="dbtn2" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Button  ID="btn2" CssClass=" thumbnail shadow tile tile-small btn-block tilegray " ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Order" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </div>
    <div id="dbtn3" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Button  ID="btn3" CssClass=" thumbnail shadow tile tile-small btn-block tile-blue masterheader " ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Purchase" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </div>
    <div id="dbtn4" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Button  ID="btn4" CssClass=" thumbnail shadow tile tile-small btn-block tilelightred" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Solution" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:Button>
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldID" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Jquery Script:

```
<script>

    function hideid() {
        var av = $('[id$=HiddenFieldID]').val();
        $('#' + av).css("display", "none");
    };
</script>
```

Now Back End code:

```
public void getpermission()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string username=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        System.Data.DataTable dt = DML.gettable("select l.`btn1`, l.`btn2`, l.`btn3`, l.`btn4`, l.`btn5`, l.`btn6`, l.`btn7`, l.`btn8`, l.`btn9`, l.`btn10`, l.`btn11`, l.`btn12`, l.`btn13`, l.`btn14`, l.`btn15`, l.`btn16` from menu l right join login m on m.id=l.Userid where m.userName='" + username + "'");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                int status=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][i].ToString());
                if (status==1)
                {
                    string columnname="d"+dt.Columns[i].ToString();
                    HiddenFieldID.Value = columnname;
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "getid", "hideid()", true);
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Not sure you are doing to correctly or not? Why don't you try to make all div runat=server and hide/show from code behind?

Comment: Let me know how will i find random div or button in ( for loop ) Id of div can be anything

Comment: Currently I can see you have 4 divs. It may be more than that. So there are no dynamic ids. If so, please post your exact code here.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri  there are 16 divs that contain 16 buttons , admin can set any of div's value to 1 in database, so when page loads it checks for what all column have value 1, div id same as columnname in database ,

So here loop checks one by one which div has 1 value and call jquery function  to hide that div ,But problem is loop is not calling jquery function one by one its executes after code behind function stops executing ..

I have posted all code beside all 16 divs i have posted only 4 for better readability

Comment: Ok. Understood. So I prefer you use code behind instead of jquery. In code behind you will find all divs using Page.FindControl method. Like loop through 1 to 16, and use page.findcontrol("div" + i). And hide/show div from code behind.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri thanks piyush for you support .. I have given my all day using this through jquery . It will be disappointing that i could't do this in jquery way ...Please answer whenever you get solution to this problem.

Do me a favor please up-vote this question .  i already got 2 minus vote that will lead this question to block if one more occur.

Comment: Well. If you really want to use jQuery its possible. Currently I see couple of issues with js function. First is, when you call js function, you didn't pass anything to that function. So do not need to call that function in for loop. Also I see that you assign column name to hidden field, which will be overright each time. So at last when js called when page loaded, it has just only one column name in hidden field. Basically you need to restructure your function.

Comment: I passed parameter from code  but was failed to retrieve its value 

<script>
        debugger
        function hideid(id) {
            var av = $('[id$='+id+']').val();
            $('#' + av).css("display", "none");
        };
    </script>
============Code behind -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "getid", "hideid()", true);

Comment: As I see, you didn't pass anything when you call, hideid() function.

Comment: I'm sorry i did but copied from above in hurry  :P i'm passing column name;

  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "getid", "hideid("+columnname+")", true);

Comment: Ok, may be you use same key each time to register js function. So instead of "getid" each time, use i variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108280/discussion-between-akash-and-piyush-khatri).

Comment: `FindControl` will not find those divs, because they are not declared to run server side.

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't work that way, and that is by design.

Please, first and foremost, familiarize yourself with the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

You will see that Code Behind is executed first and only on the server, then the resulting Page is sent to the client (browser). 
When the Page has arrived at the client, no more Code Behind is executed.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you should hide the divs in Code Behind, before sending your Page to the client.

Comment: I'm posting my query in readable format again . please refer to question for Code

there are 16 divs that contain 16 buttons , admin can set any of div's value to 1 in database, so when page loads it checks for what all column have value 1, div id same as columnname in database , So here loop checks one by one which div has 1 value and call jquery function to hide that div ,But problem is loop is not calling jquery function one by one its executes after code behind function stops executing .. I have posted all code beside all 16 divs i have posted only 4 for better readability

Comment: @Akash, I understood your problem and you are using an approach that shows you do not understand what happens when in ASP.NET. Read the article, understand when Code Behind is executed, and understand when JavaScript is executed client side.

Comment: Could you please me know how can i achieve this .. I can do this code behind finding div and setting it up visible false. I want to do this in jquery way

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't work by itself. Fix that first, learn how to write JavaScript.

Comment: jquery is working sir , I'm looking forward to answer , i know i need to learn a lot

Comment: Think of how you may get the database info to the client side. Then work with the data there, in JavaScript. I won't be writing code for you.

Comment: You are being more Enigmatic for simple problem , I wish i was using mvc so that i could have good command on html . thanks for your Enigmatic response sir .

Comment: What's the issue with HTML? That cannot be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned your code behind code is overwriting each value. So change it to a comma delimmeted string. Then in jquery change it to an array and loop through that.

Change for loop to:

```
public void getpermission()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string username=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        System.Data.DataTable dt = DML.gettable("select l.`btn1`, l.`btn2`, l.`btn3`, l.`btn4`, l.`btn5`, l.`btn6`, l.`btn7`, l.`btn8`, l.`btn9`, l.`btn10`, l.`btn11`, l.`btn12`, l.`btn13`, l.`btn14`, l.`btn15`, l.`btn16` from menu l right join login m on m.id=l.Userid where m.userName='" + username + "'");
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                int status=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][i].ToString());
                if (status==1)
                {
                    string columnname="d"+dt.Columns[i].ToString();
                    HiddenFieldID.Value = HiddenField.Value + columnname + ",";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "getid", "hideid()", true);
                }

            }
            //remove the last comma
            HiddenField.Value = string.Remove(HiddenField.Value.Length - 1);
        }


    }
```

Then inside the Jquery:

```html
<script>


    function hideid() {
        /*might need to make sure this is a string before using split */
        var av = $('[id$=HiddenFieldID]').val().split(",");
        for( a in av){
          $('#' + a).css("display", "none");
          }
    };

</script>
```